# User following a proposal not listed as a member

Tags: bug, area-51

At least one user is following the [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues?page=1&tab=votes) proposal but he is not listed as a follower.

[User profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/130158/jsantos1991).

Did I miss something? Is it a bug? Is there other users in that situation?

Comment: @bluet Yes, the specific problem is gone.